# prove that the generator of normal operator semigroup is normal

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators, normal-operator

This problem is from "A Course on Functional Analysis II" by Zhang Gongqing and Guo Maozheng, which is the textbook of a functional analysis course I'm taking.

Precisely speaking, let T(t) be a strong continuous operator semigroup on Hilbert space H, with T(t) normal for any t. Let A be the generator of the semigroup and prove that A is also normal.

The hint on the book suggests us to use Gelfand representation, but I have no idea about how to use it. Other ways seem also difficult to me. Does anyone have some idea?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you elaborate a bit on Gelfand representation?